# React OnMouseDown event is not working whereas OnMouseUp is working fine.(on SVG elements)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, mouseevent, onmousedown

I am having an svg element on which I need to capture the `mousedown` event.
Here is the code.

```
//code snippet...
<g onMouseDown={this.clickHandler}>
    <circle ...></circle>
    <text> </text>
</g>
```

Code for click handler is as simple as this.

```
clickHandler() {
    alert("mouse down")
 }
```

`onMouseUp` and `OnClick` are working fine, but not the `onMouseDown`

The same `onMouseDown` event in working fine outside the SVG (I tried on Button)

Any Idea about the error.

`React Version: 16.5.2`

Comment: onClick is equal to onMouseUp + onMouseDown.Why are you using them all?

Comment: @Root, there are some operations I want to perform when the element in mouse press and some operation as soon as the mouse button is released.

Comment: Could you post a full example? This minimal example works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/lrz0kr87kl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnMouseDown` will get a block if you are also having the drag functionality implemented.

To capture the `OnMouseDown` you need to remove `event.stopPropogation()` from your `dragStartEvent`

Another Interesting thing is if you don't want to remove `event.stopPropogation()` you can still perform the all the operation which you intend to perform on `OnMouseDown` in `dragStartEvent` event.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  onDown() {
    console.log("Down");
  }
  onClick() {
    console.log("Click");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg >
          <g onClick={this.onClick} onMouseDown={this.onDown} >
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Working fine with console.log [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161793/onmousedown-over-rides-onmouseup-and-onclick)

Comment: I think there is a typo: should `stroke-width` be `strokeWidth` ?   Here is a [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-surf-8s6gt) of a slightly modified version of the above code running in an online repl. (code is in App.js, Click "console" below the output box in order to see content of the Console.)

Comment: (I reverted theprevious edit: it changed the code itself, introducing syntax errors - it changed the html tags, probably by accident. Then edited to fix indentation, also wrapping the return html in `()` so opening div tag could be moved to next line, and all html tags could then be lined up for clarity - it's the standard way to `return ` React/HTML code.)